# How user cloudant to send app crash report in android

Tags: android, cloudant

I am using [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) to send crash report of my application. I want to use  free hosting services of Cloudant.

I had created a database on cloudant name "mobile" & generated key for it with write permission [using it](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup#wiki-all-other-couchdb-versions).

I have added acra-4.5 jar file in my app & build path.

formUriBasicAuthLogin has key, formUriBasicAuthLogin has password.

**Code use in my application class-**

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
formUri = "https://mshuiet.cloudant.com/mobile/",

 reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,

 httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,

 formUriBasicAuthLogin="Berndiverewyetheewrillyi",
 formUriBasicAuthPassword="vWqRNHUoc26SodsvtmNTWDcw",
 mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
resToastText = R.string.app_name
)

 public class Mobile extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
     ACRA.init(this);
}

 }
```

I have get exception:-

Failed to send crash report for 1375431176000-approved.stacktrace

Comment: Is that the entirety of the exception message? Seems tragically sparse.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudant, documents are created via POST. PUT against a URL like that is attempting to create a new database with the name "mobile", whereas a POST attempts to create a document within that database. Check our docs on [database](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/database.html) and [document](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/documents.html) methods for more details.

So, specifically, try changing this line...

```
httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
```

...to this:

```
httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.POST,
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the CloudAnt database name needs to be preceded by 'acra'
In your case, it would be 'acra-mobile' as per the documentation here

https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/setup

Also, your URL path should look like this (remove whitespaces)

https:// [my-user-id] . cloudant . com/ [my-database] / _design/ acra-storage/ _update/ report

and the Http method should be like this

httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.POST